# Issue in VB.Net trying to create Word and Excel Objects using a service in Windows 11

Tags: vb.net, service, createobject, windows-11

I have an issue in VB.Net trying to create Word and Excel Objects using a service.

Error message in the Event Viewer shows "Cannot create ActiveX component."

The issue only occurs on Windows 11 and the same code & service works as it should in Windows 10.

I have a service that runs as Local System account.  Every 10 minutes it runs and has code to gather the text out of Word and Excel and writes to a SQL DB.

The code that fails is below in the Try/Catch:

```
        Dim objWordApplication As Object = Nothing
        Try
            objWordApplication = CreateObject("Word.Application")
            objExcelApplication = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
            MicrosoftOfficeInstalled = True
        Catch ex As Exception
            MicrosoftOfficeInstalled = False
            gEventLog.WriteEntry("Office Not Detected: " & ex.Message & " ")
        End Try
```

It appears the CreateObject is failing, but I can't determine why, nor can i determine how to get more information written to the event log, like maybe a message number that i can research further.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Brian

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2

Comment: You will get more exception information with `ex.ToString()` instead of `ex.Message`.

Comment: Guessing this probably a 365 sub where office may not be authorized to run in the context of Local System.  Avoid using office automation especially in situations like this.

Comment: Why not `Dim objExcelApplication As New Excel.Application` instead of dealing with Object with limited properties and methods?

Comment: Thanks all for the input!  After reading the support article posted by user9938, I was able to change our code around and no longer need the CreateObject code.  I was using those statements to check for Office being installed and I no longer need to check to see if Office is installed.